# delete an object in rspec rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, destroy

I want to create an object and then delete it during an rspec test... is this possible?

This code:

```
describe User do

  it "should be invalid if email is not unique" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, id: 1, email: "g@g.com").should be_valid
    FactoryGirl.build(:user, email: "g@g.com").should_not be_valid
    User.destroy(user.id)
    FactoryGirl.build(:user, email: "g@g.com").should be_valid
  end


end
```

returns the error:

```
Failure/Error: User.destroy(user.id)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `id' for true:TrueClass
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue isn't that you can't delete the user within your rspec test - it's that your `user` object isn't getting the assignment you intended:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user, id: 1, email: "g@g.com").should be_valid
```

evaluates to true, and is assigned to `user`. Then, when you try to call `user.id`, it looks for the `id` property of `true` and gets stuck.

You might split out that particular line to:

```
FactoryGirl.build(:user, id: 1, email: "g@g.com").should be_valid
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, id: 1, email: "g@g.com")
```

or not worry about local user variable and just delete based on the email address, i.e.

```
User.destroy((User.find_by email: "g@g.com").id)
```